# unable to get local issuer certificate..installing RVM on a mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rvm, public-key-encryption, public-key

I'm trying to install RVM to set up my ruby on rails installation. I'm following this guide http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html. I'm at the stage where I have to install RVM. From the RVM install page I executed the following command 
    gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

And received the following...

```
 gpg: DBG: armor-keys-failed (KEY      0x409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 BEGIN
```

) ->0
gpg: DBG: armor-keys-failed (KEY 0x409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 END
) ->0
gpg: key D39DC0E3: public key "Michal Papis (RVM signing) " imported
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2018-08-19
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)

When I then try to execute the next command
    \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

I get back the message
    curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Not familiar with the gap tools and I'm wondering did I receive the public key and if so where would it be....and why can't I download from the server.